# Add a relative path to $PATH on fish startup

Tags: macos, shell, environment-variables, fish

I want to add ./bin directory (which is relative to current shell directory) to $PATH on fish  startup. Note that `fish` is a shell.

```
echo $PATH
set PATH ./bin $PATH
echo $PATH
```

If I place these lines inside `~/.config/fish/config.fish` the shell will echo the same collection of paths. Absolute paths are added properly.

If I open the shell and type the same `set PATH ./bin $PATH` inside some directory containing `bin` it is added successfully. However when there is no `bin` inside current directory it shows me an error.

```
set: Could not add component ./bin to PATH.
set: Value too large to be stored in data type
```

I'm running fish 1.23.1 on OS X Lion.

Comment: please indicate the underlying OS (Linux or Windows or ??), and the shell system (csh, ksh, bash, powershell, ???) Good luck.

Comment: `fish` is a shell; here's [the web site](http://fishshell.com/).

Comment: Sorry for being unclear about what shell I am using.

Comment: For OS X users trying to set path to Homebrew / brew packages, I successfully used: set PATH /usr/local/bin $PATH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like `fish` won't add a non-existing directory path to PATH. That applies to relative paths too. But if you create `bin` directory in your home directory `set PATH ./bin $PATH` will work properly on each startup since it is executed from home. This is kind of a hack though.

Comment: `pushd ~ ; set PATH ./bin $PATH ; popd`  (But again, I don't think this is a good idea.)

Answer (score 70):

The best way I have found to **persistently add a path to your `$PATH`** is

```
set -U fish_user_paths $fish_user_paths ~/path/name
```

This *prepends* to `$PATH`. And since it's persistent, the path stays in `$PATH` on shell restarts.

It's more efficient than putting a command in your `config.fish` to modify your `$PATH`, because it only runs once compared to running on every shell restart.

The variable [`fish_user_paths` is intended to be set by the user](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/527#issuecomment-13811988)<sup>1</sup>, as stated by [ridiculousfish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1441328/ridiculous-fish), the maintainer of fish.

---

Consider creating a fish function for convenience: <sup>2</sup>

```
# ~/.config/fish/functions/add_to_path.fish
function add_to_path --description 'Persistently prepends paths to your PATH'
  set --universal fish_user_paths $fish_user_paths $argv
end
```

And use it as:

```
$ add_to_path foo bar  # Adds foo/ and bar/ to your PATH
```

---

Notes

1. On that page the author gives the example `set -U fish_user_paths ~/bin`. This overwrites `fish_user_paths` with a single value of `~/bin`. To avoid losing existing paths set in `fish_user_paths`, be sure to include `$fish_user_paths` in addition to any new paths being added (as seen in my answer).
2. My dotfiles contain a slightly more advanced version that skips adding duplicates https://github.com/dideler/dotfiles/blob/master/.config/fish/functions/add_to_user_path.fish

Comment: More details, discussion here: https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/527

Comment: should -x flag be used for PATH?

Comment: @YichuanWang there should be no need since [that's already done in the `fish_user_path` handler](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/blob/2f3123e1757f495afc799f0c734283d4513db0f8/share/config.fish#L121)

Answer (score 16):

I'd never heard of `fish` before this.  I just installed it so I could try it out (and deleted a few paragraphs I had written here before realizing that `fish` is a shell).

It looks like `set PATH dir-name $PATH` is the right syntax to prepend a directory to `$PATH`.

But adding a *relative* directory name to `$PATH` is almost certainly a bad idea, and your shell is doing you a favor by warning you when the directory doesn't exist.  (`fish` is designed to be user-friendly.)

Use an absolute path instead:

```
set PATH $PWD/bin $PATH
```

and first check whether `$PWD/bin` exists, printing an error message if it doesn't.

As for the "`set: Value too large to be stored in data type`" message, could you be adding the directory to your `$PATH` multiple times?  There should be some way to check whether a directory is already in `$PATH` before adding it.

Comment: But I really want `./bin` be in my PATH, so that if I `cd` in some directory I can call any executables in its `./bin` subdirectory without prepending `bin/`. Zsh allows me to do this. $PWD/bin will be set once and won't be relative to current directory.

Comment: I'd say that's a bad idea for the same reason having `.` in your `$PATH` is a bad idea.  Suppose you `cd` into `/tmp/bad`, and somebody has created a `/tmp/bad/bin/ls` that runs `rm -rf $HOME`.  If I know there's a command in `./bin` that I want to execute, I can type `bin/whatever`; if I don't, I probably don't want to execute it.  But if you insist, it looks like `fish` only checks whether the directory exists when you run the `set` command.  Just make sure you're in a directory that has a `./bin` subdirectory when you set your `$PATH`; it will stay there when you `cd` to other directories.

Answer (score 12):

I think the answer is that using `set -U` is a red herring. Instead, add the following to `~/.config/fish/config.fish`:

```
if status --is-interactive
    set PATH $PATH ~/.local/bin;
end
```

Comment: sorry, this probably doesn't answer the original question, but I'll leave it for anyone else looking for a hint!

Answer (score 7):

direnv http://direnv.net/ is a good utility to help with what you're doing.

Generally, prepending $PATH with ./bin is insecure, as anyone with write-access to a shared directory could hide malicious code in e.g. ./bin/ls. That code would execute when you run ls in the shared directory.

direnv does not solve this problem (it works based on .envrc files, but anyone could be placing those), but at the very least it makes you aware when you cd into a directory that $PATH is getting modified:

```
$ cd my_project
direnv: loading .envrc
direnv export: ~PATH
```

Comment: Why the downvote? Direnv seems like a useful tool for the problem, plus the mention of security implications is something that most here didn't think of.

Comment: Newer version of direnv actually address this attack vector by requiring the user to whitelist allowed `.envrc` files. Whenever a new `.envrc` file is encountered direnv won't allow it's execution until the user ran `direnv allow` or (`direnv edit` and saved the file).

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think there is only a small risk in adding `.` to the `$PATH`, *so long as it's the last item*, because a rogue `ls` (or whatever) in the CWD will *not* be found before `/usr/bin/ls`.

I add this in my `config.fish`:

```sh
contains '.' $PATH; or set --export PATH $PATH .
```

You could do similar for adding `./bin`, again in the *last* position:

```sh
contains './bin'; or set --export PATH $PATH ./bin
```

Two things are going on here:

1. This is setting `$PATH` directly, just as with other shells. This won't persist across shells.
2. This checks that it's not already in the `$PATH`, so that sub-shells won't get longer, redundant entries in `$PATH`